# How do I specify where to start in a dependency graph that has no fixed start point

Tags: build, makefile, scons

I'm using a tool chain that is more like a web.  There are lotys of alternate start points, all resulting in a single final output.

I typically use make or scons - actually, I prefer scons, but my team highly prefers make. I'm open to other build tools.

E.g. final_result depends on penultimate

```
final_result: penultimate
```

penultimate may be made in any of several different ways:

If starting from file1, then

```
penultimate: file1 ; rule1
```

If starting from file2, then

```
penultimate: file2 ; rule2
```

Q: how do I specify to start with file2, not file1?

I suppose that I could use a command line switch and ifdeffing.  But I would prefer to have make or scons figure out "Hey, there's a file2 around, so I should use rule2, not fil1/rule1".  In part because the web is much more complex than this...

Worse, sometimes an intermediate on one path may be a start on another.  Let's see:

A .s produces a .diag

```
foo.diag: foo.s
```

But sometimes there is no .s, and I just have a .diag that somebody else gave me already built.

A .diag produces a .heximg, and a .hwresult

```
foo.hwresult: hwsim foo.heximg

foo.heximg: foo.diag
```

But sometimes I am given a .img directly

Etc.

I just want to write the overall dependency graph, and say "OK, now here's what I have been given - now how do you get to the final result?"

With what I have now, when I am given, say, a foo.img, I get told (by make in this case) "foo.s not dfound".  Because make wants to go all the way back in the dependency graph to tell if foo.img is out of date, whereas I want to say "assume foo.img is up to date, and work forwrads for stuff that depends on foo.img, instead of going back for stuff that foo.img depends on."

Comment: actually, there are multiple final outputs.  I just wanted to simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it all with pattern rules (implicit rules).  If you specify an explicit rule then make considers that a hard dependency and if some portion of the dependency is not met, make will fail.

If you use an implicit rule then make will consider that a POSSIBLE way to build the target.  If that way doesn't work (because some prerequisite does not exist and make doesn't know how to build it) make will try another way.  If no way works, and the target already exists, make will just use that target without having to update it.

Also you say "a .diag produces a .heximg and a .hwresult" then gave a strange example makefile syntax that I didn't recognize, but FYI with pattern rules you can specify that a single command generates multiple outputs (you can't do this with explicit rules):

```
%.heximg %.hwresult: %.diag
```

Here's the bad news: the only way to define an implicit rule in GNU make is if there is a common "stem" in the filename.  That is, you can write an implicit rule that converts foo.diag to foo.heximg by writing a pattern rule "%.heximg: %.diag", because they have a common stem "foo", but there's no way to create a pattern rule for a compilation from "foo1" to "penultimate", because they don't share a common stem.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the typo in the pseudo-example "a .diag produces a .heximg and a .hwresult" (it's a pseudo-example becase I did not provide rules, tryng to elide stuff).

Comment: I must admit that I could swear that with explicit rules you could specify multiple outputs.  Gotta read/test.

Comment: No.  You CAN write a rule like "foo bar biz: baz; command", but that does NOT mean that one invocation of <command> will convert "baz" into the files "foo", "bar", and "biz".  The above is shorthand for writing 3 rules: "foo: baz; command", "bar: baz; command", and "biz: baz; command".  In other words, <command> will be run 3 times, once for each output.  Sometimes you can get away with this because when make goes to build the second one it sees it's already up to date.  But if you enable parallel builds you'll get 3 invocations most times.  And if you use -d you'll see make checking all 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but probably you're looking for [Double-Colon Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon):

> **Double-colon** rules are explicit rules written with `::` instead of `:` after the target names. They are handled differently from ordinary rules when the same target appears in more than one rule.
>
> Double-colon rules are somewhat obscure and not often very useful; they provide a mechanism for cases in which the method used to update a target differs depending on which prerequisite files caused the update, and such cases are rare.